# error: Cannot find symbol in Java (1.7)

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

When I try compiling my source file, it returns the error `error: cannot find symbol`. I'm shiny new to Java so this is probably really easy for you but please try to use code as simple as possible while explaining properly.
Code:

```
public class BeerSong {
public static void main (String[] args){
    int beerNum=99;
    String word="bottles";
    while (beerNum>0){
        if (beerNum==1){
            word="bottle";
        }
        if (beerNum>0){
            System.out.printIn(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall.");
            System.out.printIn("Take one down.");
            System.out.printIn("Pass it around.");
            beerNum=beerNum-1;
        } else {
            System.out.printIn("No more bottles of beer on the wall.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Step one: install Eclipse or NetBeans and don't study Java with `vi` and `javac`.

Comment: It's `println` not `printIn`.

Comment: Works fine. Just an advice: `beerNum=beerNum-1` = `beerNum--`.

Comment: @PakkuDon it's `printIn` not `printIn`? They both look the same to me

Comment: Lower-case L vs Upper-case I. :P

Comment: @KabbageKobra It's a bug in your eyes, or screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `System.out.println()` instead of `System.out.printIn..`you are using capital "I" i for integer instead of small "l" l for letter

Answer (score 1):

check this line `System.out.printIn` it should be `System.out.println`

replace these lines

```
 System.out.printIn(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall.");
 System.out.printIn("Take one down.");
 System.out.printIn("Pass it around.");
```

with

```
System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall.");
System.out.println("Take one down.");
System.out.println("Pass it around.");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT

```
System.out.printIn
```

RIGHT is

```
System.out.println
```

(small letter L)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `printIn()` in java. It should be `println()`

change

```
System.out.printIn();
```

to

```
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `printIn` instead of `println`, hence the error, since `printIn` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BeerSong {
public static void main (String[] args){
int beerNum=99;
String word="bottles";
while (beerNum>0){
    if (beerNum==1){
        word="bottle";
    }
    if (beerNum>0){
        **System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall.");**
        **System.out.println("Take one down.");**
        **System.out.println("Pass it around.");**
        beerNum=beerNum-1;
    } else {
        **System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall.");**
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your sops statement have syntax error. there is no (I) in println. It is (l)

Wrong One: `System.out.printIn()`

Correct One: `System.out.println()`